# Why is "prompt" important for inputting strings?

Tags: string, matlab, if-statement

I was just writing a simple if else test for a string. I had tried to get it to work by just using

```
str = input("input: ")
```

Usually I don't have to use prompt, is prompt something I should get into the habit of using all the time? or is it only necessary for working with strings? 
I know it's a basic question, I just found it difficult to wrap my head around.
Thanks in advance!

```
#If testing is entered the program will return true, anything else will 
#return false

prompt = ("input: ")
str = input(prompt,"s");
answer = ("testing");
test = strcmp(str,answer);
if test = 1;
  disp("true")
else
  disp("false")
end
```

Comment: prompt value only affects, well, how input is prompted at interactive shell. It does not have any influence on how inputed value will be processed later. `str` does not know it came from input of given prompt, it's just strong, nothing more, nothing less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general the more informative and diligent you are *now* the more you will thank yourself later when you're debugging a month down the line when you've forgotten what your program was supposed to do :p  It has nothing to do with string inputs, this is an equally appropriate input statement:

```
>> prompt = 'Enter a valid matrix: ';                             
>> Matrix = input (prompt);
>> assert (ismatrix (Matrix))    % ... etc
```

Appropriate prompting, validation of inputs etc, is essentially just helpful documentation / appropriate user interface / safe code. In the same way that you should always strive for self-documenting code by choosing representative and well thought names for your functions, variables, and only commenting when necessary and with *helpful* comments rather than useless narrative.

e.g. compare the following two snippets of code:

```
function done = doit(a,b)
% haha, just like starsky and hutch! I'm so funny!
  if b, 
  max(abs(a),abs(b)); else, % make b [] otherwise this will fail!
     max(abs(a),abs(input(num2str(b)))); end; % please work!
     done = ans; % done and dusted!
  end
```

```
function Out = getLargestAbsolute(a,b)
% GETLARGESTABSOLUTE takes two arguments and returns the one with the greatest
% absolute value. If only one argument is given, the user will be asked to
% input a value from the terminal. Both values should be scalars.

  assert(isscalar(a), '"a" must be a scalar argument');
  if nargin < 2; b = input('Please enter a number and press ENTER: '); end
  assert(isscalar(b), '"b" must be a scalar argument');

  Out = max (abs (a), abs (b));
end
```

In theory the two are functionally equivalent. But guess which one is a) safer, b) easy to debug a month later when I've forgotten what it was supposed to do. :)

Answer (score 1):

That `prompt` here is just a variable that stores the string "input: ". You can use any other self-explanatory names you think that makes sense, e.g., `my_prompt` or `prompt_message`.

Using a variable to store the prompt message like this gives you some advantages, especially for big projects: Imagine, a same prompt message is hard-coded at several different parts in your code. Now if you want to modify that prompt message, you will need to go through your entire code and modify its every single occurrence; conversely, if you store the prompt message as a variable and every `input` just uses that variable, then you can simply modify that variable and all prompt messages will be automatically fixed.

In general, it is a good habit to separate the "data" (in this case, the prompt message) from the "code logic" (the input function), instead of hard-coding the data in the code logic. That said, if your project is just a very small prototype that you need to quickly put together, then you may not benefit as much from this separation; you might as well just use hard-coded prompt messages.

Answer (score 0):

Normally the user (or you when you debug) does not know what to type or when to type it. A prompt is almost exclusively there to help the user to do things right. Assume you are entering a date. Then you may want to know the format,

```
str = input('date (yy/mm/dd)> ', 's');
```

Most well known programs have prompts when they are supposed to read human input. MATLAB uses the prompt `'>> '` which shows when it is ready to process the next input. Linux ftp prompts like this `>`. Also Linux has an editable prompt for the terminal. Further, telnet has sometimes no buffer, so the prompt is necessary for the user to know when to type the next input.

You may say that "Ok, but text editors, they does not prompt". In case you believe this however, what would you then call the flashing vertical line?

It is up to you whether or not you prompt, but in case you do not you may end up with a lot of bugs and/or bug reports.